# Convert html into string

Tags: html, string, telerik, editor

How can I convert Html into string. For example I have html: `<p>This is Test</p><p></p><p>Test</p>`. I want to convert html into this:

This is a test

Test

I don't want the `<p>` tag to be printed on the screen but I want them to behave as actual paragraphs.

I have tried HtmlDecode but that doesn't work either. I am getting the string from mvc telerik editor.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

**Update:**
I did partially solve my problem by using HTML.Raw in my view which converted the html into string. I was wondering if there is any equivalent to Html.Raw that I can use on the server side too i.e. in my controller??

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a parser. [HTMLAgility](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) pack is a tool that is constantly recommended here.

Comment: Thanks for replying back. I did go to the Html agility pack link but didn't quite get how is it going to help me. I did partially solve my problem though by using HTML.Raw in my view which converted the html into string. I was wondering if there is any equivalent to Html.Raw that I can use on the server side too i.e. in my controller??